# C - Making UTP server/client chatroom with select()

Tags: c, select, tcp, client-server

I'm supposed to make the server broadcast the message it gets from a client to all the other clients connected.

The actual broadcast works, but I have no idea how to stop the clients from infinitely printing "[client]Received from friends:" when I CTRL+C the server,

OR

how to stop the Server from infinitely printing "[server]Message received..." when I CTRL+C any of the connected Clients. Or how to add a verification somewhere so that the Client will disconnect when trying to send the string "quit"

Maybe I'm asking for too much, but could someone please explain to me what exactly does select(..) do? I understand that it's monitoring the FDs, but I can't fully understand what's going on(step-by-step) after 1 second. Does it go through all FDs ,1 second for each then repeat? I kind of get the idea, but not entirely.
Thank you either way

SERVER

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define PORT 3050     //The port used by Clients

extern int errno;

char * conv_addr (struct sockaddr_in address)
{
  static char str[25];
  char port[7];


  strcpy (str, inet_ntoa (address.sin_addr));   /* client IP */

  bzero (port, 7);   /* PORT */
  sprintf (port, ":%d", ntohs (address.sin_port));
  strcat (str, port);
  return (str);
}

void Msgs(int fd,int sd,fd_set fds,int nr);

int main ()
{
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;        /* struct for Server */
  struct sockaddr_in client_addr;        /* struct for Clients */
  fd_set readfds;                        /* ready-to-read File Descriptors */
  fd_set actfds;                         /* active/existant File Descriptors */
  struct timeval tv;                     /* time thing, for select() */
  int ServerSocketFD, ClientSocketFD;       /* Socket descriptors */
  int optval=1;             /* ????*/
  int fd;           /* FD used to pass through all FDs */
  int nfds;         /* max number of FDs */


  (ServerSocketFD = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0));


  setsockopt(ServerSocketFD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval) );


  bzero (&server_addr, sizeof (server_addr));

  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
  server_addr.sin_port = htons (PORT);


  bind (ServerSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr) );


  listen (ServerSocketFD, 5);     //listen to maximum 5 clients,no more

  FD_ZERO (&actfds);                    
  FD_SET (ServerSocketFD, &actfds);     /* Add the only existant one for now */

  tv.tv_sec = 1;        /* wait 1s */
  tv.tv_usec = 0;

  nfds = ServerSocketFD;    /* max value of currently used FDs */

  printf ("[server] Waiting at port :%d...\n", PORT);
  fflush (stdout);


  while (1)      /* serve clients CONCURRENTLY */
    {
        bcopy ((char *) &actfds, (char *) &readfds, sizeof (readfds));          /* copy all existing FDs in actfds vector to the read-to-read-FDs vector */

        select(nfds+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        if (FD_ISSET (ServerSocketFD, &readfds))     /* if ServerSocket is ready to read stuff */
        {
            bzero (&client_addr, sizeof (client_addr));

            int len = sizeof (client_addr);
            ClientSocketFD = accept (ServerSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &len);

            if (nfds < ClientSocketFD) /* adjust max FD, for select */
                nfds = ClientSocketFD;

            /* Add this accepted sockets' FD to the existing FDs */
            FD_SET (ClientSocketFD, &actfds);

            printf("[server] Client connected, with FD %d, from this address %s.\n",ClientSocketFD, conv_addr (client_addr));
            fflush (stdout);
        }

        for (fd = 0; fd <= nfds; fd++)  /* all FDs*/
        {
            if (fd != ServerSocketFD && FD_ISSET (fd, &readfds))        /* is a client ready to send/get messages? */
            {
                Msgs(fd,ServerSocketFD,actfds,nfds);
            }
        }
    }
}

void Msgs(int fd,int ServerSocketFD,fd_set fds,int nrFD)
{
  char buffer[100];     
  int bytes;        
  char msg[100];        

  bytes = read (fd, msg, sizeof (buffer));

  /*
  if(strstr(msg,"quit")!=0)
  {
    FD_CLR(fd, &fds);
    close(fd);
    exit(1);
  }
  */
  printf ("[server]Message received...%s\n", msg);

  for(int i=0;i<=nrFD;i++)
  {
    if(i!=fd && i!=ServerSocketFD)
    {
        write (i, msg, bytes);
    }
  }

}
```

CLIENT

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


extern int errno;

int port;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int ClientSocketFD;         
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr; 
    char msg[100];      
    char reply[100];


    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf ("[client] Sintax: %s <server_address> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }


    port = atoi (argv[2]);
    ClientSocketFD = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons (port);


    connect(ClientSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,sizeof (struct sockaddr));



    int pid;
    if((pid=fork())==-1)
    {
        perror("Error fork()");
        exit(10);
    }
    if(pid==0)  //CHILD
    {
        while(1)
        {
            bzero(msg,100);
            printf ("[client]Send something to other clients: ");
            fflush (stdout);

            read (0, msg, 100);     
            if(strstr(msg,"quit")!=0)
            {
                break;
            }

            write (ClientSocketFD, msg, 100);
        }

        exit(7);
    }
    else if(pid > 0) //PARENT
    {
        while(1)
        {
            bzero(reply,100);
            read (ClientSocketFD, reply, 100);

            printf ("[client]Received from friends: %s\n", reply);
        }
    }

    close (ClientSocketFD);

}
```

Comment: `select(nfds+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);select(nfds+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);` :: you need to (re)set `tv` every time you call select. select changes it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea how to stop the clients from infinitely printing "[client]Received from friends:" when I CTRL+C the server

`read()` returns 0 if the server terminates, so replace the `while(1)` loop in the client PARENT by

```
        while (bzero(reply, 100), read(ClientSocketFD, reply, 100) > 0)
            printf("[client]Received from friends: %.100s\n", reply);
        kill(pid, SIGTERM); // terminate also the child
```

(and `#include <signal.h>`).

> how to stop the Server from infinitely printing "[server]Message received..." when I CTRL+C any of the connected Clients

`read()` returns 0 if the client terminates, so call

```
                Msgs(fd, ServerSocketFD, &actfds, nfds);
```

change the `Msgs()` type to

```
void Msgs(int fd, int ServerSocketFD, fd_set *fds, int nrFD)
```

and in `Msgs()` after `bytes = read (fd, msg, sizeof (buffer));` add

```
  if (bytes <= 0) { FD_CLR(fd, fds); close(fd); return; }
```

> could someone please explain to me what exactly does select(..) do? I understand that it's monitoring the FDs, but I can't fully understand what's going on(step-by-step) after 1 second. Does it go through all FDs ,1 second for each then repeat?

As wildplasser noted in his comment, `select()` possibly changes the timeout argument to indicate how much time was left, so after 1 second without FD activity we may well end up with a zero timeout and a useless busy loop. We need a `select()` timeout only if we want to do something when none of the monitored FDs gets ready within a certain time, so in your case it's better to specify no timeout at all:

```
        select(nfds+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```